# tanstack react-query ENOENT error when uninstalling v5 and installing v4

Tags: react-query, tanstackreact-query, enoent, trpc

**FULL ERROR:**

> ./node_modules/@tanstack/react-query/build/modern/index.js Error:
> ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
> 'C:\Users\riodj\infoscan\node_modules@tanstack\react-query\build\modern\index.js'

**CONTEXT:** after installing and setting up trpc using

```
npm install @trpc/server@next @trpc/client@next @trpc/react-query@next @trpc/next@next @tanstack/react-query@latest zod
```

I had uninstalled `@tanstack/react-query` individually, as the installed version was v5 and I wanted to use react-query v4.

So I installed v4 with

```
npm install @tanstack/react-query@4.36.1
```

and then I get the aforementioned error message on my localhost:3000

**ADDITIONALS:**

This is my terminal after install v4 process
[terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0vtL.png)

**WHAT I'VE TRIED:**

changing `@tanstack/react-query` version in `peerDependencies` under `node_modules/@trpc/next` in the `package-lock.json` file (from ^5.25.0 to ^4.36.1)